# Create monitoring folder with powershell to change a specific column (from general to date) in multiple Excel sheets loading into it

Tags: excel, powershell, format

New to powershell
I am unable to change the format of the column and also how to make it run continuously

```
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xl.visible = $true
$Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open("44r.xlsx")
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheets.Columns.("G").GeneralFormat = "m/d/yy"
$Workbook.SaveAs("C:\scripts\*.xlsx",1)
$Workbook.Saved = $True
$xl.Quit()
```

[image]

Comment: I am not much of a powershell user, but should this line `$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets` include the worksheet name? Such as `$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets("Sheet1")` for example

Comment: In addition to @K.Dᴀᴠɪs hints you are switching between singular and plural `$Workbook` <> `$Workbooks`, so use `$Worksheets = $Workbook.worksheets(1)` or `$Worksheets = $Workbook.worksheets('sheet1')` but also here the singular `$Worksheet` makes more sense.

Comment: Have you tried using `.Numberformat` instead of `.GeneralFormat`